# PyQt5 "xcb" not found

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, archlinux

I created an app with Qt designer. When I launching my app It throws this error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Error throws then program executes this line:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

This is looks like there is some missing dependencies. **How to fix this problem?**

I tried to reinstall `libxcb`, but this didn't help.

*P.S.: I'm using manjaro linux and python 3.5.2*.

*P.P.S.: I get this error then tried to launch `ipython qtconsole`*

Comment: What is the output of this command: ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so

Comment: second command?

Comment: @eyllanesc, [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/v167uWsK) is output of `ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`

Comment: try with: sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/

Comment: @eyllanesc, didn't help. Is it important that I don't have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder? But I found `/usr/lib/qt/` and `/usr/lib/qt4/`

Comment: How did you install pyqt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc it was installed by anaconda

Comment: And why do not you install with: pacman -S python-pyqt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried now, but pacman said what it is already installed, I confirmed reinstall and it didn't help

Comment: When you use that you should use the python of your system not the one that gives you anaconda.

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried both, but error still throws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in that I installed anaconda with sudo, and with sudo all works fine. I reinstalled anaconda without sudo and now all is ok